# SSL ошибка 80. После рукопожатия

Tags: linux, c, windows, openssl, rdp

Здравтвуйте. Проблема заключается в следующем. Пытался разобраться как работать с библиотекой openssl. Для создания соединения использую следующий код

```
BIO * bio;
SSL_CTX * ctx;
SSL * ssl;

void initSSL()
{
   SSL_library_init();
   SSL_load_error_strings();
   ERR_load_BIO_strings();
   OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
   ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_method());
}

int connection_to_host(char * host, int port)
{
bio = BIO_new_connect("192.168.0.5:3389");
if(bio == NULL){
    printf("\nBIO connection error\n");
    return -1;
}

if(BIO_do_connect(bio) <= 0){
    printf("\nBIO connection error\n");
    return -1;
}
}

void send_tpdu_connection_request(){
char * host = "192.168.0.5";
int port = 3389;

char cookie[] = "Cookie: mstshash=User\r\n\1";
char padding[] = {0x08, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

struct packet {
    char tpkt;
    char zero;
    short len;
    char tlen;
    char connectionRequestCode;
    char DestinationReference[2];
    char SourceReference[2];
    char ClassOption;
    char cookie [sizeof(cookie)];
    char padding[6];
} pack;

printf("\nstrlen(cookie) = %i\n", strlen(cookie));
printf("\nsizeof(cookie) = %i\n", sizeof(cookie));

memcpy(&pack.cookie, cookie, sizeof(cookie));
memcpy(&pack.padding, padding, 6);
pack.tpkt = 0x03;
pack.zero = 0x00;
int packet_length = 4+6+sizeof(cookie)+7;
pack.len = htons((short)packet_length);
pack.tlen = (char)packet_length-5;
pack.connectionRequestCode = 0xE0;
bzero(&pack.SourceReference, 2);
bzero(&pack.DestinationReference, 2);
pack.ClassOption = 0x00;

connection_to_host(host, port);

int size = BIO_write(bio, &pack, packet_length);
printf("\nWRITE size=%i errno=%i\n", size, errno);
size = BIO_read(bio, buffer, 4096);
printf("\nREAD size=%i errno=%i\n", size, errno);
printdatadump(buffer, size);
}

void do_tls_handshake()
{
bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
SSL_set_mode(&ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, "192.168.0.5:3389");
if(BIO_do_connect(bio) <= 0){
    printf("\nERROR SSL CONNECTION; errno = %i\n", errno);
    printf("%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
    return;
}
if(SSL_get_verify_result(ssl) != X509_V_OK)
{
    printf("\nSERVER CERTIFICATE NOT TRUSTED\n");
}
}

void send_spnego()
{
char spnego[] = {   0x30, 0x37, 0xA0, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x02, 0xA1, 0x30, 
                    0x30, 0x2E, 0x30, 0x2C, 0xA0, 0x2A, 0x04, 0x28, 0x4E,
                    0x54, 0x4C, 0x4D, 0x53, 0x53, 0x50, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 
                    0x00, 0x00, 0xB7, 0x82, 0x08, 0xE2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x01, 0xB1, 0x1D, 0x00,
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x0F 
                };
                int statement = BIO_write(bio, &spnego, sizeof(spnego));
                statement = BIO_read(bio, buffer, 4096);
                if(statement <= 0){
                    printf("\nERROR SSL CONNECTION; errno = %i\n", errno);
                    printf("%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                }
 }

 int main()
{
initSSL();
send_tpdu_connection_request();
do_tls_handshake();
send_spnego();
}
```

После чего на моменте чтения данных от сервера получаю ошибку

```
error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error
```

Как я понял, эта ошибка может быть не связана с самим ssl. Подключение к хосту клиентом FreeRDP получается успешно. Логи wireshark показывают, что пакеты передаваемые по сети идентичны. (Собственно с FreeRDP и копировал их). В чем может быть проблема? Вообще никаких мыслей нет. Уже 2е сутки с этим разобраться не могу

Comment: Есть вероятность, что хост использует древнюю версию TLS.

Comment: "alert internal error", значит в дампе есть пакет ALERT с кодом ошибки. Обычно - да, он скорее всего говорит о том, что сервер не поддерживает версию SSL, которую использует клиент. В дампе ее тоже видно в каждом пакете хендшейка, обратите на нее внимание при сравнении.

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваши ответы. Да. Действительно код ошибки есть. Код ошибки 80, интерпретируется как internal error. Больше ничего не вижу. Возможно не туда смотрю. Версии перепробовал все. FreeRDP при таких же условиях работает нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я неправильно отправлял AUTHENTICATE сообщение протокола NTLM. Необходимо было вычислять Значения NTProofStr, MIC, EncryptedRandomSessionKey. Помогла в решении вопроса документация MS-CSSP, MS-NLMP